# On the irrelevancy of putting good questions on hold and later closing them

Tags: discussion, closing, closed-questions, on-hold-questions

There is a great problem on this site. I have posted many good mathematics problems on this site but they are usually put on hold and then later closed and now I have reached my question limit not because my questions were off topic, not at all! They were on topic and I read all the instructions which were being followed by my question, the only difference was that it was tough and nobody gave answer. People could not understand the importance of my questions and downvote them, not seeing the concepts behind them. While the questions which are built upon theories and which are so common that any layman can answer them have hundreds of votes on them and the sources of answers are sites like wolfram, Wikipedia etc.

Is this the usefulness of this site, if you want to know about the topic, you would instead of searching yourself asking mindless questions from others who would all the more be ready to answer it but those questions which are hard and nobody has solved them on this site aren't thrown and people who have easily gained reputation take advantage of it by down-voting such questions so that they are never seen by any sensible people who are members on this site.
So now I really have taken a decision to unsubscribe from this site, if somebody reading this, I think definitely some people would downvote this question.

**If you all want, I would like to have your opinion on this matter and what you think about this site. Do you consider this a fair site where people are rewarded fairly on their efforts? If yes, do not fail to give the reason of closing my questions which were framed correctly, I tried solving them, but couldn't proceed but they were cruelly closed**
*Do not hesitate to reply!*

Comment: Are your questions important? Assuming so, your postings don't say anything about that. That would be example of *context or other details* missing from your posts.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You posted [Sum of digits, sequence (no theory)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2222168/sum-of-digits-sequence-no-theory). You were told, "Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it." You made no effort to do so. (By the way, you got six answers to this question [two have since been deleted], but you didn't accept any of them)

You posted [Range of the function y={f(x)}](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230774/range-of-the-function-y-fx) and again made no effort to improve (and again neglected to accept an answer).

You posted [How to solve the equation $\left\lfloor x\left\lfloor x\left\lfloor x\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor\right\rfloor\right\rfloor\right\rfloor=88$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2235111/how-to-solve-the-equation-left-lfloor-x-left-lfloor-x-left-lfloor-x-left-lfloo) and again made no effort to improve the question. You got a long comment, "Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are/ what you have tried with so far; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post." but made no effort to implement its advice. And again you accepted no answer.

I've seen enough – I'm not going to bother to look at your other questions. But, please, the advice that people give you, take it seriously. Your questions may be interesting, but your presentation is close to offensive.

Comment: :D Took the time to accept some of the answers now, including this one, so yay...

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered reading why your questions were closed? Here's a snippet at the "closed as off-topic" explanations that has appeared below [Sum of digits, sequence (no theory)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2222168/272831).

[image]

Of particular interest, note that the "improve the question" links to

[How to ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959)

This link includes much information I recommend going through.

It also provides a link to the [help center: What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)

On top of that, it may also be of interest that these links were provided to you before you posted your very first question! Indeed, you have to go through this [advice page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice) in order to proceed to your first question, which has many of the links provided above and more.